# Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: The account being accessed does not support http

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I'm inserting a new xml file created with in the code into our file share folder in Azure. I have Secure transfer required set to enabled but still getting "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: The account being accessed does not support http".  I'm not sure where to look.  Here is my code.

```
            const string storageAccountName = "TestAccount";
            const string storageAccountKey = "AccountKey";
            var storageAccount =
                new CloudStorageAccount(
                    new StorageCredentials(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey), false);

            //See if FileShare folder is there
            var share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("MainFolder");
            share.CreateIfNotExists();

            //Get a reference to the root of the FileShare folder
            var rootDirectory = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            
            //Get a reference to the next level folder
            var folder1 = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("Folder1");
            folder1.CreateIfNotExists();
            
            //Get a reference to the next level folder
            var pendingFolder = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("Pending");
            pendingFolder.CreateIfNotExists();

            pendingFolder.GetFileReference("tested.txt").UploadText("Testing CreateCloudFileClient");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet), the second parameter specifies to use https:

```
public CloudStorageAccount (
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials storageCredentials,
    bool useHttps);
```

Change this code:

```
   var storageAccount =
                new CloudStorageAccount(
                    new StorageCredentials(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey), false);
```

To:

```
   var storageAccount =
                new CloudStorageAccount(
                    new StorageCredentials(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey), useHttps: true);
```